# Python print result to variable with correct formatting

Tags: python, string, variables, printing, python-2.x

I have a script that uses raw_input to enter a IPv4 IP address in CIDR format.

```
#<--BEGIN IPv4 CIDR FORMATTING -->
# Get address string and CIDR string from command line
sys.argv = raw_input("Type IPv4 address in CIDR format ")
(addrString, cidrString) = sys.argv.split('/')
```

The functions defined in the script converts the user inputted CIDR (1.1.1.1/16) to normal IPv4 format.

Print result with code: `print addrString, ".".join(map(str, mask))` outputs to screen as 1.1.1.1 255.255.0.0 which is correct.
But when I assign `addrString, ".".join(map(str, mask))` to a variable, like `var2 = addrString, ".".join(map(str, mask))` it's shown as ('1.1.1.1', '255.255.0.0')

How can i strip the unneeded signs like

> (

and

> '

and

> ,

when assigning to a variable?

Comment: You're creating a tuple with the comma.  If you just want a space, you can use `addrString + " " + ".".join(map(str, mask))`

Comment: Thanks Tom, This did the trick instantly!

Answer (score 1):

You're printing a tuple. That's what tuples look like when printed. It sounds like you just want the two values together as a string, so you could do something like;

```
display_value = " ".join(var2)
print var2
```